# Subprocess.call fails to run but if output is pasted to cmd it runs

Tags: python-3.x

I have some issues with subprocess that I can't figure out why its throwing a exception, been trawling other posts and ya old google but none of the posts resembles this

```
lamepath = ("C:\Windows\System32\lame.exe --preset extreme ")
wavuse = ("E:\test\wavefile.wav")
mp3use = ("E:\test\mp3file.mp3")
subprocess.call(lamepath +wavuse +" " +mp3use)
```

but it throws this exception: C:\Windows\System32\lame.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

if I print() the same statement I get: 
C:\Windows\System32\lame.exe --preset extreme "E:\test\wavefile.wav" "E:\test\mp3file.mp3"

if i paste this output to cmd the print sting runs perfectly..

C:\Windows\System32\ is in the PATH and the lame.exe does exist. COMSPEC is also correct

Comment: try subprocess.call(lamepath +wavuse +" " +mp3use , shell=True)

Comment: As I understand you only use the shell=true for native cmd operations like "dir" etc.but have tried with no luck ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So today I learned something new, when you are a 32-bit process on 64-bit Windows, and
you try to refer to files in \Windows\System32, the operating system
"helpfully" rewrites the path so you actually refer to
\Windows\SysWOW64, which is where the 32-bit executables and DLLs live.